# Showing only alternate grid line numbers in Y-axis in winforms chart c#

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

In Windows forms chart, I wanted to show only the alternate grid label numbers in the y-axis.

For example, if the y-axis grid lines are at 15,20,25,30,35.. I would like to show only the numbers 15,25,35.. but the lines for 20,30,40,..should stay.

Please refer the attached image for reference [image: Please click here for Reference Image]

---

Is there any default property for AxisY to achieve this? I tried different properties of AxisY but none seem to work well for my scenario.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

I generate the series like below

```
Random rno = new Random();
        for(int i=10; i< 100;i++)
        {
            int rnum = rno.Next(15, 150);
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i,rnum);
        }
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 15;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 150;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 5;
        //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset = 5;
```

Comment: can you show us some code on how you're currently generating the chart?

Comment: How are you generating chart on the form?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Please find the snippet I have attached

Comment: @CodeWarrior Please find the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing only the interval of the grid itself:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 15;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 150;

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 10; // Interval of the written numbers
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 5; // Interval of the grid
```

If you want to add tickmarks (as shown in your picture) to the gridlines that does not show a number you can do it with: `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorTickMark.Interval = 5;`